# how to call spring mvc3 with jquery ajax post between two applications?

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have two web applications hosted on a server. From one I am trying to do $.post to the second application (spring mvc3). I am able to successfully hit the url of the second application but I do not get response back of the ajax call.

App1 JS Code (http://localhost:7777/app1/test.html) -

```
var serialisedFormData = $("form").serialize();
 $.post("http://localhost:8080/app2/doSomething", serialisedFormData, function (data) {
        alert("job done");        
    }, "json");
```

App2 Java Code -

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething")
        public @ResponseBody String doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, 
 @RequestParam("d") String data) {

            try {
                   ... do something here ...
                   return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Exception occured when doing something", e);
                return "failure";
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you. What does `POST /app2/doSomething` return when you execute the request outside of a browser, such as with `curl` on the command line? How do you know you are not getting a response back - your response handler only seems to issue an alert. What does your browser's developer tools show you as the response that the HTTP call to `/app2/doSomething` is returning?

Comment: Are they deployed in the same application server instance and have the same domain - else it could simply be that the browser is blocking cross-domain request.

Comment: Maybe your `post` call is missing ".html"? `$.post("http://localhost:8080/app2/doSomething.html...`

Comment: @BijuKunjummen - yes I also fear that is a cross-domain request. What can be a solution in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by removing "json" type from my jquery post call.

```
$.post("http://localhost:8080/app2/doSomething", serialisedFormData, function (data) {
        alert("job done");        
    });
```

and adding a header to my response

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething")
        public @ResponseBody String doSomething(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam("d") String data) 
     {

            try {
                   ... do something here ...
                   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                   return "done";
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Exception occured when doing something", e);
                return "failure";
            }
        }
```